# Counter 0-30 But Clock connected - VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I made a counter 1-30. but I got this
[image: My schematic]
[image: I got this]
My schematic here. I remove counter0-3
[image: 3]
and It's here I found the problem here. It's the clock connected with a new loop
[image: Clock connected with new Clock loop]
So I want to increase the size of the clock. Like this
[image: Like this]
I'm a rookie here, I don't know how to do that. Please give me an idea, thanks

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
        
entity counter0_9x is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        clk_B : in std_logic;
        reset : in std_logic;
        counter : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        clk_o : out std_logic
    );
end counter0_9x;
        
architecture Behavioral of counter0_9x is
signal counter_up : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        
begin
    process(clk,reset)
    variable num : integer := 0;
    begin 
        if(reset='1')then
            counter_up <= "0000";
        elsif(clk'event and clk = '1')then
            if clk_B = '0' then
                if num <= 2 then
                    if counter_up = "1001" then
                        counter_up <= "0000";
                        num := num + 1;
                        clk_o <= '1';
                    else
                        counter_up <= counter_up + '1';
                        clk_o <= '0';
                    end if;
                else
                    if counter_up = "0000" then
                        counter_up <= "0000";
                        num := 0;
                        clk_o <= '1';
                    else
                        counter_up <= counter_up + '1';
                        clk_o <= '0';
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    counter <= counter_up;
end Behavioral;
```

Update!!!
I have tried combinational but I still can't shrink "clk_o"
[image: 6]

```
architecture Behavioral of counter0_9x is
signal counter_up : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin
    process(clk,reset)
    variable num : integer range 0 to 2 := 0;
    begin 
        if(reset='1')then
            counter_up <= "0000";
        elsif(clk'event and clk = '1')then
            if clk_B = '0' then
                if num <= 1 then
                    if counter_up = "1001" then
                        counter_up <= "0000";
                        num := num + 1;
                    else
                        counter_up <= counter_up + '1';
                    end if;
                else
                    if counter_up = "0000" then
                        counter_up <= "0000";
                        num := 0;
                    else
                        counter_up <= counter_up + '1';
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    counter <= counter_up;
    
    with counter_up select
    clk_o <= '1' when "0000",
               '0' when others;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

At firth sight this is caused by assigning the signal ("clk_o") insight a sequential process (process that is (edge) triggered by your clock).
This creates a flipflop that stores the signal value until the next rising edge of the clock.

You want to achive combinational logic. You have to create a separate process for the assignment of signal "clk_o" without any clock. (Don't forget to add the necessary signals to the sensitivity list.)

It might also be helpful to visualize the synthesis of your vhdl code using pen and paper to better predict the extracted logic.

Comment: ok, I have tried combinational but I still can't shrink "clk_o". what should I do next?